# Simplifying $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} (2k + \log_2(k) - 1)$

Tags: summation

I'm trying to simplify the following summation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (2k + \log_2(k) - 1)$$.

I've basically done the following:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}  (2k + \log_2(k) - 1) \\
=
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \log_2(k) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1\\
=
\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \log_2(k) - (n-1)$$

Now I'm trying to do deal with this term $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \log_2(k)$, but I'm a bit confused.

My gut tells me I can do the following:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \log_2(k)\\
=
\log_2(1) + \log_2(2) + \ldots + \log_2(n-1)\\
= 
\log_2(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k)\\
= 
\log_2((n-1)!)$$

Using that $\log_a(b) + \log_a(c) = \log_a(b \cdot c)$.

However, I'm not convinced this is an entirely valid reasoning because I can't find any rules/identities for dealing with $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \log_2(k)$.
Is this correct or are there any rules to apply?

Comment: Your reasoning is perfectly valid, and the validity of the simplification for any number of log terms follows easily from the fact that $\log x + \log y = \log(xy)$.

Comment: Ok good. Does that mean the rule $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_a(k) = \log_a(\prod_{k=1}^{n} k)$ holds in general?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $n(n-1)$ instad of $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ since you do the summation of $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2k$?

Comment: @Mythio yes it does! You already stated that $\log(b) +\log(c) = \log(b\cdot c)$. Now you can simply add further terms and you get the rule you mention.

Comment: @macydanim You are absolutely right, I forgot the 2 infront of the summation (I always move the multiplication constant out of the summation first). However, the end result would indeed be $n(n-1)$ EDIT: sigh...got to keep paying attention..

Comment: @Mythio sorry I don't understand that. If you have $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2k$ then the result is $n(n-1)$. I don't know what you state with "However, the end result would ..."

Comment: @macydanim: third time is a charm...its always in the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just so people know this has been answered)

You right

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k = \log (n!)$$

If you want to justify it formally, you can try using induction.